# How to send Char letters vs. Char numbers over SerialPort?

Tags: c#, serial-port

This has been bizarre for me. I must be missing something simple. I am able to do the following:

```
serPort.Open();
char[] data = new char[1];
data[0] = '7';
serPort.Write(data, 0, 1);
```

I am able to receive data from my hardware device. If I do the following, then I don't get a response.

```
serPort.Open();
char[] data = new char[1];
data[0] = 'L';
serPort.Write(data, 0, 1);
```

On my hardware device, I make the change to look for either 'L' or '7'. I can get '7' to work every time but when I try to send an 'L' to my hardware device, it is unable to read that I am sending an 'L'. Is there something different about sending a character 'L' vs. a char '7'?.... It works for every number that I try but when I use letters, my communication is unsuccessful.

Additional note: Using Putty, I am able to send an L and receive a response.

Thank you!

Comment: What does happen when instead you send the byte 0x4C (L letter), does it still fail the same way ? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143551(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: How many data bits are you specifying when you open the port? '7' fits in 5 bits, whereas 'L' requires 6 bits. Since it is possible to set the port to 5 bits, that seems like more than a coincidence. Without debugging, I do not know what that result would be.

Comment: @Aybe. I tried sending 0x4C and it failed the same way. I've tried using a byte array instead of char array as well.

Comment: @JamieMeyer. I'm specifying 8 bits when I open the port

Comment: You definitely need to get hold of the specs of your device and read them.

Answer (score 0):

I was using a USB hub that was behaving intermittently. It was working all along. I plugged in my device directly to the laptop instead of the USB hub and it is working flawlessly now.